# Android sms-auto sender

Tags: android, calendar

I'm looking for an app that would remind clients of appointments a day in advance.

I use [google calendar](https://www.google.com/calendar/render) in order to organise my appointments. I'm looking for an android app that could:

- Retrieve appointments in google calendar
- Send at a given time before the appointment, in an automatic manner, a text to remind the client of his appointment, the date and time at which it takes place.

It would be better if it:

- Could get its orders directly from google cal, or, if it works with another calendar, could be easily interfaced with google calendar.
- Was avaible from Play store, as I don't want to bother installing and updating it manualy.